# Scala-Spark program - need to save into S3 bucket with initial record based key name

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have a a very large list of records in S3 with a layout like this --
textfield1, textfield2, numField1, textfield3, textfield4

I need to group the records by textField1 and textField2, sort the grouped records by numField1, and write out the each group to an s3 bucket as records under key textfield1-textfield2-numfield1 with numfield1 being the field value from the first record in the sorted group.

So if we have input records like the following

```
a,b,45,ab45f3,ab45f4 
d,f,29,df29f3,df29f4
c,b,23,cb23f3,cb23f4
a,b,22,ab22f3,ab22f4
c,b,32,cb32f3,cb32f4
d,f,14,df14f3,df14f4
```

I need the following in the output:

```
s3://output-recs/output/a-b-22 with contents
    a, b, 22, ab22f3, ab22f4
    a, b, 45, ab45f3, ab45f4
s3://output-recs/c-b-23 with contents
    c, b, 23, cb23f3, cb23f4
    c, b, 32, cb32f3, cb32f4
s3://output-recs/d-f-14 with contents
    d, f, 14, df14f3, df14f4
    d, f, 29, df29f3, df29f4
```

This is what i tried -- which worked partially but left me with a few loose ends

```
val lists = sc.textFile("s3n://input-rec/allrecs") 
               map { line => line.split(",").toList }

val sg = lists.map(rec => ((rec(0), rec(1)), rec)).groupByKey.mapValues 
              { t => t.toList.sortBy(l => l(2)) }

val p = sg.count.toInt

val res = sg.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(p)).map {
  case (key, value) => value
}.map(l => l.map(_.mkString(",")).mkString("\n"))

res.saveAsTextFile(s"s3n://output-recs/output")
```

When I tried this, I ran into a couple of problems --

1. It groups into three sets and creates three PART files -- but sometimes one of the three PARTs is blank and one of the other two PARTs contains two sets. Is there a way to force it so that each partition is restricted to just 1 set?
2. I am not able to figure out a good way to rename the "PART" files to match the naming convention I wanted. I was able to do this by a post processing script that reads the first line, parses and reads the first three fields, and renames the file. However, it seems inelegant and takes a long time to run with large files.